# Show line breaks in a textarea input field

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, forms

I have searched for an answer to this question to no avail.

I am entering text from a form teatarea field into a MySQL database with line breaks included, and when returned and written to html with PHP I am first exploding the data and putting it into an array, then adding each array item within either paragraph tags or list tags in an unordered list.

The problem is when users input text into the textarea field there is no way to distinguish visually a text wrap from a line break, it would be much clearer to the user if there was a way to distinguish between the two, possibly with a space after a line break or a symbol to show the end of a line, like the paragraph symbol.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Could you provide us w/ some of your code?

Comment: can't be done with a standard text area. you can't "format" the text in there. if you're using a online editor, like TinyMCE, you could potentially insert a special display char to show line breaks v.s. html `<br>` and whatnot.

Comment: In TinyMCE you can force a paragraph with [ENTER] and a break by using [SHIFT]+[ENTER]

Comment: @Cups But can the user tell the difference visually? I think that's what he wants, a visual indicator of line breaks.

Comment: Thanks for the input, yes I have considered using an html editor, but the people I am doing the work for think that their non web savvy clients would be more confused by an html editor than it would be worth.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments on not to use html editors available, you can mimic the same as follows

You can have a simple javascript function which captures each key request (onkeypress() to the textarea) and if that key is '\n' then place a delimiter sort of thing, else just let it out

**UPDATE**

The traditional html textarea is only capable of displaying ascii characters(that too very limited)
So go for the new HTML5 tag `contenteditable` like

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

On this div you can apply the javascript to get the required result.

For examlpe if the user presses 'Enter key' (say) then you can append a `<hr/>`to the div element. There by you get a horizontal line whenever Enter is pressed which differentiates it from the text wrapping or invisible characters

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was thinking of how that could work, but if you use html tags like <br /> they show up literally in the textarea and if you use ASCII line break \n it is invisible which is the problem I started with. In a textarea when you use the enter key it puts in an invisible ASCII \n .

Comment: Thanks @funtime, I'll experiment with that solution.